# Script font Identification help please

Tags: fonts, font-identification, script

Poor original script font for identifying. I’ve tried everything to ID the original is just too poor. [image]

I edited it heavily and was able to get a search. No exact match but some possible substitutes. I would add the redo but don't know how to add an image to existing request.
Thanks again.

enter link description herfile:///Users/donaldwalls/Desktop/AthleticsB.jpg
e

Comment: What, exactly have you tried? Please look at [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions] to be sure you're meeting the Font ID requirements. Have you, for example, used a photo editing software to un-warp the text and submitted that to whatfontis? Did you decide No-Seven-Regular, though close [https://www.whatfontis.com/NFS_No-Seven-Regular.font?text=Athletics] wasn't close enough due to not having enough weight difference between right and left hand strokes?

Comment: Have you tried removing the curve and reversing the image before using online identifiers?

Comment: There are literally thousands of script fonts. Might be better to just start searching manually until you get something close. Have a look at those on [Dafont](https://www.dafont.com/mtheme.php?id=6&text=Athletics&fpp=100) perhaps?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I have been searching various font providers by doing a manual search. I am going to try to photo edit and create a cleaned up version for search on whatfontis etc.